# How can we set the metric value as a label in Prometheus alerting rules

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

For example, let's assume a custom metric with no labels is being exported.

```
# TYPE ping_count counter
ping_counter 22
```

I have a prometheus alerting rule:

```
groups:
 - name: Count greater than 5
   rules:
   - alert: CountGreaterThan5
     expr: ping_counter > 5
     for: 40s
     labels:
       route: ping_counter
```

I wish to see the `route` label have the ping_counter metric value in AlertManager, like:
`route="3"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `{{ $labels.ping_counter }}` in labels. For example

```
groups:
 - name: Count greater than 5
   rules:
   - alert: CountGreaterThan5
     expr: ping_counter > 5
     for: 40s
     labels:
       route: {{ $labels.ping_counter }}
```